# Given a set of crossword clues, generate a compatible crossword grid

Tags: ruby, algorithm, combinations

I have a number of crossword clues in two arrays for across and down clues (each clue is a pair - [clue_number, clue_length]. I am trying to find a compatible grid for this crossword, (assuming all answer words are made of the same letter, i.e, don't bother about the actual answers - just use the length and number to find a compatible grid).

I assume that the grid is 13 x 13 (this test example, I know, has a 13 x 13 solution). So far, I am computing all the combinations for positioning the 'across' words amidst black squares. The thought was to then check each option and if it fits the down clues as well, accept it. However, this already has ~10^17 combinations (with grid dimension of 13 x 13 and the above test dataset). I am wondering if there is a more efficient approach to solve this in a reasonable time. The code I have so far is shown below:

```
ACROSS_CLUES = [
  [1, 5],  [6, 5],  [9, 7],  [10, 5],  [11, 5],  [12, 5],  [13, 7],  [15, 3], [17, 4],[18, 6],[19, 5],  [20, 6],  [22, 4],  [24, 3],  [25, 7],  [26, 5],  [27, 5], [28, 5],  [29, 7],  [30, 5],  [31, 5]]

DOWN_CLUES = [
  [2, 6],  [3, 6],  [4, 3],  [5, 5],  [6, 7],  [7, 4],  [8, 6],  [12, 5],  [13, 5],  [14, 5],  [15, 5],  [16, 5],  [18, 5],  [19, 7],  [21, 6], [22, 6],  [23, 6], [25, 5],  [26, 4],  [28, 3]
]

ACROSS_DIRECTION = :across
DOWN_DIRECTION = :down

# merge the across and down clues into a single array sorted by the clue number
CLUES = ACROSS_CLUES.map{|ac|ac + [:across]} + DOWN_CLUES.map{|dc| dc + [:down]}.sort_by{|c| c.first}

UNINITIALIZED = -2
BLACK = -1
BLANK = 0

SIDE = 13
SIZE = SIDE ** 2

# a fragment is a string of clue_length characters (number followed by blanks), which is rendered in the grid
def get_fragment(clue)
  clue_number = clue[0]
  clue_length = clue[1]
  fragment = [clue_number] + Array.new(clue_length - 1, BLANK)
end

# returns the first compatible grid found
def get_grid
  fragments = [] 
  ACROSS_CLUES.each do |clue|
    fragments << get_fragment(clue)
  end
  across_clues_length = fragments.flatten.count

  grid = Array.new(SIZE - across_clues_length + fragments.length, UNINITIALIZED) 
  grid_length = grid.length
  (0..(grid_length - 1)).to_a.combination(fragments.length).each do |num_locations|
    fragments.each_with_index do |fragment, fragment_index| 
      num_location = num_locations[fragment_index]
      grid[num_location] = fragment
    end
    grid.flatten!
    # TODO: check if grid is compatible, return if valid; reject if invalid
    grid = Array.new(SIZE - across_clues_length + fragments.length, UNINITIALIZED) 
  end
  grid
end

grid = get_grid
```

Comment: I'm actually not sure what the question is.

Comment: @Tommyixi - given the clues you get in a typical crossword (across and down clues with clue number and length of word), and assuming the grid is not available, generate a compatible crossword square grid ( with numbers, blank spots and black squares). More details are in the question.

Comment: If this works but is just too slow, you may ask it at CodeReview.se